# Logging into CP in EE 1.x after migration

Tags: control-panel, login, ee1

I just inherited an EE 1.6.7 project. I'm attempting to log into /system in my local dev environment and each time I'm just redirected to the CP login page, which does not have any images or styles.

I remember from way back when that it's doing this because the Site URL & other paths don't match. I also remember (and was just reminded when I blew things up) that I can't modify these values in the database directly.

What's the solution to be able to log into the CP homepage in a different environment than what's stored in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried a number of different options to try to get this to work. Dug up a post on setting 1.6.7 to use dynamic URLs & paths to try to enable the CP in my local dev environment:

http://old.kennwilson.com/2007/11/configuring-expression-engine-for-multiple-servers

When I was still unable to log in, I ended up following [this advice](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewreply/1027386/):

> Generally it helps to change admin part to session only or cookies
>   only, I like session only but it seems some hosting companies have
>   session encrypted and that can cause problems.  Also, in Chrome I have
>   extension for cookies, so I delete cookies when such things happen.
>   And second problem I can have is when I do test, login to test without
>   a problem, go to production, and cannot login or when I go from one
>   client to another on another server only because I opened different
>   CPs several times.
>
> Try that ... change session only or cookies and session to cookies
>   only or vice versa, delete browser cache and try again OR of you do it
>   several times and it does not work, wait for few minutes.

Simply clearing the cache & deleting cookies did not work. I had to change the following from:

```
$conf['admin_session_type'] = "c";
```

to:

```
$conf['admin_session_type'] = "s";
```

Then I was able to log in.

Answer (score 0):

When this happens to me, I clear browser cache and add the following into my config file:

```
$conf['cookie_domain'] = "";
$conf['cookie_path'] = "";
$conf['cookie_prefix'] = "";
$conf['admin_session_type'] = "cs"
```

Comment: Part of the problem I ended up tracking down was that I had my full localhost URL for cookie_domain. I.e., client.clearbold.localhost:8888. The :8888 had to go.